# Connection in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to make a registration form. If you can give me some tips if my code is wrong or not proper

it still showing me this prepare
($sqlinsert); $user = $_POST['user']; $pass = $_POST['pass']; $email = $_POST['email']; $lname = $_POST['lname']; $fname = $_POST['fname']; $stmt->bind_param($user, $pass, $email, $lname, $fname); $stmt->execute(); $rowcount = $stmt->affected_rows; if ($rowcount > 0) { echo "Success!"; } else { echo "Error!"; } //CLOSE EXECUTE $stmt->close(); ?>

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('local','root','','dbtform');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO tblform (user, pass, email, lname, fname) 
    VALUES ('sssss',?,?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sqlinsert);

    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];



    $stmt->bind_param($user, $pass, $email, $lname, $fname);
    $stmt->execute();

    $rowcount = $stmt->affected_rows;


    if ($rowcount > 0)
{
echo "Success!";
}

else
{
echo "Error!";
}

//CLOSE EXECUTE
$stmt->close();

?>


    <head>
        <title>Animated Form Switching with jQuery</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Expand, contract, animate forms with jQuery wihtout leaving the page" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="expand, form, css3, jquery, animate, width, height, adapt, unobtrusive javascript"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <script src="js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/ChunkFive_400.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Cufon.replace('h1',{ textShadow: '1px 1px #fff'});
            Cufon.replace('h2',{ textShadow: '1px 1px #fff'});
            Cufon.replace('h3',{ textShadow: '1px 1px #000'});
            Cufon.replace('.back');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>Rythreion</h1>
            <h2>Demo: click the <span>orange links</span> to see the form animating and switching</h2>
            <div class="content">
                <div id="form_wrapper" class="form_wrapper">
                    <form class="register">
                        <h3>Register</h3>
                        <div class="column">
                            <div>
                                <label>First Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="fname" />
                                <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label>Last Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="lname"/>
                                <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="column">
                            <div>
                                <label>Username:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="user"/>
                                <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label>Email:</label>
                                <input type="text"  name="email"/>
                                <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label>Password:</label>
                                <input type="password" name="pass" />
                                <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom">
                            <div class="remember">
                                <input type="checkbox" />
                                <span>Send me updates</span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Register" />
                            <a href="index.html" rel="login" class="linkform">You have an account already? Log in here</a>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <form class="login active">
                        <h3>Login</h3>
                        <div>
                            <label>Username:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="user" />
                            <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Password: <a href="forgot_password.html" rel="forgot_password" class="forgot linkform">Forgot your password?</a></label>
                            <input type="password" name="pass" />
                            <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom">
                            <div class="remember"><input type="checkbox" /><span>Keep me logged in</span></div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Login"></input>
                            <a href="register.html" rel="register" class="linkform">You don't have an account yet? Register here</a>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <form class="forgot_password">
                        <h3>Forgot Password</h3>
                        <div>
                            <label>Email:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" />
                            <span class="error">This is an error</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom">
                            <input type="submit" value="Send reminder"></input>
                            <a href="index.html" rel="login" class="linkform">Suddenly remebered? Log in here</a>
                            <a href="register.html" rel="register" class="linkform">You don't have an account? Register here</a>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <a class="back" href="http://google.com">back to the Codrops tutorial</a>
        </div>


        <!-- The JavaScript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                    //the form wrapper (includes all forms)
                var $form_wrapper   = $('#form_wrapper'),
                    //the current form is the one with class active
                    $currentForm    = $form_wrapper.children('form.active'),
                    //the change form links
                    $linkform       = $form_wrapper.find('.linkform');

                //get width and height of each form and store them for later                        
                $form_wrapper.children('form').each(function(i){
                    var $theForm    = $(this);
                    //solve the inline display none problem when using fadeIn fadeOut
                    if(!$theForm.hasClass('active'))
                        $theForm.hide();
                    $theForm.data({
                        width   : $theForm.width(),
                        height  : $theForm.height()
                    });
                });

                //set width and height of wrapper (same of current form)
                setWrapperWidth();

                /*
                clicking a link (change form event) in the form
                makes the current form hide.
                The wrapper animates its width and height to the 
                width and height of the new current form.
                After the animation, the new form is shown
                */
                $linkform.bind('click',function(e){
                    var $link   = $(this);
                    var target  = $link.attr('rel');
                    $currentForm.fadeOut(400,function(){
                        //remove class active from current form
                        $currentForm.removeClass('active');
                        //new current form
                        $currentForm= $form_wrapper.children('form.'+target);
                        //animate the wrapper
                        $form_wrapper.stop()
                                     .animate({
                                        width   : $currentForm.data('width') + 'px',
                                        height  : $currentForm.data('height') + 'px'
                                     },500,function(){
                                        //new form gets class active
                                        $currentForm.addClass('active');
                                        //show the new form
                                        $currentForm.fadeIn(400);
                                     });
                    });
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

                function setWrapperWidth(){
                    $form_wrapper.css({
                        width   : $currentForm.data('width') + 'px',
                        height  : $currentForm.data('height') + 'px'
                    });
                }

                /*
                for the demo we disabled the submit buttons
                if you submit the form, you need to check the 
                which form was submited, and give the class active 
                to the form you want to show
                */
                $form_wrapper.find('input[type="submit"]')
                             .click(function(e){
                                e.preventDefault();
                             });    
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: You got your quotes messed up around `$sqlinsert`.

Comment: @ChrisCooney it keeps on showing  prepare($sqlinsert); $user = $_POST['user']; $pass = $_POST['pass']; $email = $_POST['email']; $lname = $_POST['lname']; $fname = $_POST['fname']; $stmt->bind_param($user, $pass, $email, $lname, $fname); $stmt->execute(); $rowcount = $stmt->affected_rows; if ($rowcount > 0) { echo "Success!"; } else { echo "Error!"; } //CLOSE EXECUTE $stmt->close(); ?>

Comment: @user2111371 The comments are not well-suited for large code fragments. Include it directly in the question instead.

Comment: @henrik i already include it.

Comment: The extra double-quote here needs to be removed `VALUES "('sssss`

Comment: i already try it but still the same problem showing up.

Comment: Close the `}` which was opened by the `if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {` after the call to `exit()`.

Comment: Actually, it looks like your server may not be processing PHP at all. Does this filename end in .php? Are you actually accessing it with a web server, rather than just reading the file in your browser?

Comment: If you view your page source, you are likely to see _all_ your PHP code there, since it has not been parsed by the server at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you can give me some tips if my code is wrong or not proper

Sure.
Your code is both wrong and improper because it is using mysqli.
You have to use PDO instead.

Just a sketch to give you an idea:
first, create a connection

```
$dsn  = 'mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost;charset=utf8';
$opt  = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

then, run your query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblform (user, pass, email, lname, fname) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($_POST); // you may wish to unset non-used fields from POST first
if ($stmt->rowCount())
{
    echo "Success!";
}
```